# why oracle jdbc driver truncate leading zero when convert number to string

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

when the field type in db is number and java bean's field type is string, oracle jdbc driver will convert the number to string with the leading zero truncated, such as `0.5` to `.5`.

I have traced the source code of jdbc driver implementation of oracle, then I found this code below in class of `oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor`:

```
String getString(int var1) throws SQLException {
   byte[] var3 = this.rowSpaceByte;
            int var4 = this.columnIndex + this.byteLength * var1 + 1;
            byte var5 = var3[var4 - 1];
            byte[] var6 = new byte[var5];
            System.arraycopy(var3, var4, var6, 0, var5);
            NUMBER var7 = new NUMBER(var6);
            String var8 = NUMBER.toString(var6);
            int var9 = var8.length();
            **if(var8.startsWith("0.") || var8.startsWith("-0.")) {
                --var9;
            }**

            if(var9 <= 38) {
                return var7.toText(38, (String)null).trim();
            } else {
                var8 = var7.toText(-44, (String)null);
                int var10 = var8.indexOf(69);
                int var11 = var8.indexOf(43);
                if(var10 == -1) {
                    var10 = var8.indexOf(101);
                }

}
```

Comment: is this NumberCommonAccessor part of some new ojdbc jar? Previously I never faced this issue but now I also face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> why oracle jdbc driver truncate leading zero when convert number to
>   string

An implicit conversion works that way. The number datatype  doesn't have any leading 0, 
2 is just 2, not 002 not 00000002.
You can use `to_char` function in the query to convert a number to a string using some format with leading zeroes, for example:

```
select to_char( 1,'09999' ) as X,
       to_char( 22, '0999999999' ) as y
from dual;

X      Y         
------ -----------
 00001  0000000022
```

Comment: but why when the jdbc driver convert the same value to number data type of java(such as int or long),there is no this kind of convertion?